# React Native - issue with flexDirection

Tags: react-native

I am trying to put a button (custom component made from TouchableOpacity inside View) and an image in a view.....and have them sit side by side.
See code below

```
<View
  style={{
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  }}
>
  <MyButton
    to_extraStyle={{
      backgroundColor: '#03A9F4',
      width: 100,
      height: 60,
      alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    }}
    onPress={this._imagePickHandler}
  >
    CHOOSE PIC
  </MyButton>
  <Image
    source={{ uri: this.state.localImgUrl }}
    style={{
      width: 100,
      height: 60,
      borderColor: 'black',
      borderWidth: 1,
      alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    }}
  />
</View>
```

When I remove `flexDirection: 'row'` you can see both the image and the button....they sit on top of each other....but with `flexDirection: 'row'` included, the image disappears and you can only see the button.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the value of width as `%`.

```js
<View
  style={{
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  }}
>
  <MyButton
    to_extraStyle={{
      backgroundColor: '#03A9F4',
      width: "50%",
      height: 60,
    }}
    onPress={this._imagePickHandler}
  >
    CHOOSE PIC
  </MyButton>
  <Image
    source={{ uri: this.state.localImgUrl }}
    style={{
      width: "50%",
      height: 60,
      borderColor: 'black',
      borderWidth: 1,
    }}
  />
</View>
```

### Example

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={s.container}
>
 <TouchableOpacity style={s.touchable}>
      <Text style={{color:"#ffffff"}}>Button </Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
      <Image source={{uri: 'http://i.imgur.com/IGlBYaC.jpg'}} style={s.backgroundImage} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const s = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundImage: {
      width: "50%",
      height: 60,
      borderColor: 'black',
      borderWidth: 1,
  },
  touchable: {      
   backgroundColor: '#03A9F4',
      width: "50%",
      height: 60,
      justifyContent:"center",
      alignItems:"center"
      },
  container: {
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove `alignSelf` on both `MyButton` and `Image` and they will sit side by side.

If what you wanted to obtain with `alignSelf` is to align `MyButton` at the very left and `Image` at the very right then add `justifyContent: 'space-between'` to your view.